# Exclude site from Compability View policy

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-server-2008, group-policy

I have a client who enforces the policy in IE that all local intranet sites be loaded in the Compatibility View.

Unfortunately our webapp doesn't support this and gives alot of issues in the comp. view.
Is there a way to specifically exclude a site from this policy without having to include it in our code ?

Comment: It makes more sense to update your code once rather than tell every client that uses your web app to change their policy settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Group Policy, you can use the Site to Zone assignment list to place the site in question into the trusted sites zone instead.  Compatibility view is disabled by default in that zone.

Answer (score 10):

To tell Internet Explorer not to use Compatibility Mode on your site, use the following meta tag (or a variation thereof) in the `head` section of your site:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=EDGE" />
```

Note that this tag **must** be the first tag inside the `head` tag. For more information, visit: [Specifying legacy document modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net you can also put the following into the web site's web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <clear/>
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=8; IE=9; IE=EDGE" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```